# Patterns in Higher Exponents

Tags: sequences-and-series

I recently found a sort of pattern that I am not sure what can be done with it, and it involves all positive integer exponents. If you make an inverted Pascal’s triangle, like this, where the top has a sequence of numbers to a certain power, for example squares, and subtract from right to left:

$$1,4,9,16,25\\
 3,5,7,9\\
  2,2,2,2;$$
As you can see, the numbers repeat after a certain amount of levels. The pattern for squares and cubes has been known for a very long time, I suppose, but if you try it with higher powers such as 4:

$$1,16,81,256,625,1296,2401\\
15,65,175,369,671,1105\\
50,110,194,302,434\\
60,84,108,132\\
24,24,24;$$
And this repeats so that for $x$ to the power of $y$, on the $y^{\text{th}}$ row, you will get a corresponding number on this sequence
$$1,2,6,24,120,720$$, where every number is multiplied by an increasing integer. In this case, $x^4$  increases by $24$ each time on the $4^{\text{th}}$ row. For $x^5$, increases by $120$ each time on the $5^\text{th}$ row, and so on.
What does this pattern suggest (sorry if someone has already asked this, I just noticed this and wanted an explanation, also sorry if you have difficulty reading this)?

Comment: If you take enough, $n$,  derivatives of $x^n$ you get the constant $n!$

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand you have are saying:
$$\begin{matrix}
1^2&&2^2&&3^2&&4^2&&5^2\\
&3&&5&&7&&9\\
&&2&&2&&2
\end{matrix}$$
where the top row can be to any integer power. The reason for this is each row you go down you are reducing the power but increasing the coefficient of a series. So:
$$\text{row 1:}\quad x^2-(x-1)^2=2x-1\\
\text{row 2:}\quad [2x-1]-[2(x-1)-1]=2$$
doing the same thing for cubes you get:
$$\text{row 1:}\quad x^3-(x-1)^3=3x^2-3x+1\\
\text{row 2:}\quad [3x^2-3x+1]-[3(x-1)^2-3(x-1)+1]=6x-6\\
\text{row 3:}\quad [6x-6]-[6(x-1)-6]=6$$
What we are effectively doing here is taking a discrete derivative of a function repeatedly, the number of times as the power. As an equation:
$$\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^nx^n\equiv n!$$
Now if you look at the factorials you will see this is the pattern you are describing:
$$1!=1\\2!=2\\3!=6$$
etc. Hope this helps